# member of a collection?

Tags: java, collections

I have two classes, Foo and Bar. Each Foo has a name and a bunch of items. Bar contains a bunch of Foo's, each with a unique name.

Bar has a method, AddEntry that takes a fooName and an item (1) if a foo with fooName is already in the Bar, adds another item to the Foo or (2) if a foo with fooName is not in the Bar, creates a Foo with that name and add the item to the new Foo.

This is an outline of how I'm implementing.  Is there a better way?  I'm just learning Java, but this seems clunky

```
class Foo { // a name and some items
    String fooName;
    List<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>;
    Foo(name) {...} // create a named Foo
    AddtoFoo(item) {...} // add an item to this Foo
}

class Bar { // a bunch of foo's
    List<Foo> fooList = new Arraylist<Foo>;

    void AddEntry(String fooName, Object item) {
        boolean member = false;
        for(Foo foo : fooList){
            if{foo.name == fooName) {
                member = true;
                foo.AddtoFoo(item); // adds an item to this foo
                break;
             }
        }
        if(member == false) {
            Foo foo = new Foo(fooName); // creates a named foo
            foo.AddtoFoo(item);  // adds the item
            fooList.add(foo);  // maintain our list of foo's
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should compare `String` equality by using `foo.name.equals(fooName)`

Comment: Is your example complete, or merely a representation? If it's complete, you could use a Map<String, List<Object>> to store everything, and then use the contains method on map for adding the items.

Comment: It's a representation, but the key is that Bar contains a list of Foos, each of which has a name and a list of items.

Comment: <goes off to read up on map, given the trend in comments so far>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `Map<String, Foo>` to map the foo name to a foo object.

```
Map<String, Foo> fooMap = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
```

Thus you could do

```
Foo foo = fooMap.get(fooName);
if( foo == null)
{
  foo = new Foo(fooName);
  fooMap.put(fooName, foo);
}
foo.AddtoFoo(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a `Map` instead, which you can look up an object by a key.

```
Map<String,Foo> fooMap = new HashMap<String,Foo>();
foo.put("name_of_foo",new Foo());
```

Then your `addEntry` might look like this:

```
void addEntry(String fooName, Object item){
    Foo foo = fooMap.get(fooName);
    if(foo == null){
       foo = new Foo();
       fooMap.put(fooName,foo);
    }
    foo.addToFoo(item);
}
```

Also, you should compare `String` equality by using `foo.name.equals(fooName)`

Answer (score 2):

In bar class you should use HashMap instead of ArrayList with FooName as key and Foo as pair. Since HashMap has o(1) searchingtime which you are doing with a for loop itreation in arraylist.

Comment: Tried not to give away code snippet thinking @foosion is learning :)

Answer (score 2):

If foo's name is just there for the lookup, perhaps a `Map<String,List<Foo>>` (and removing Foo.name) would save you from coding that much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a HashMap in Bar, instead of using a List. Use the fooName as unique key. This way, in Bar you can check if the instance of Foo is already known in your current bar much faster (just something along the lines of this):

```
Map<String, Foo> fooMap = new HashMap<String, Foo>();

... 
Foo foo = fooMap.get(fooName);
if(foo == null)
{
   fooMap.add(fooName, new Foo(fooName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the foo must stay in the same order, you could replace your list of foos with a `Map<String, Foo>`. Searching for an existing foo would become a O(1) operation rather than a O(n) operation.

Even if the foos must stay ordered, you could use a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct but if your are looking for the right foo object, instead of using a `List`, use a `Map`, like the `HashMap`. Use as key the `fooName` and as value the `Foo` object. Get the object you are looking with `get(fooName)`and if returns null, does not exists and the add a new `Foo` with `put()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way and more maintainable way would be to use hashCode and use contains.

public int hashCode() {
 return fooName.hashCode();
}

This is must faster than for: loop. Althought it doesn't provide you O(1) complexity but it guarantees (theoretically) fixed retrieval ~ O(1)

Also get() method does the same on hashMap. It uses hashCode to retrieve the object from the Map.